# Array indexing with copy constructor, assignment operator and index operator overload

Tags: c++, array, reinventing-the-wheel, constructor, overloading

The code below is a custom array class that handles indexing, copying, printing, etc. explicitly.
Is there a better approach for specification (declaration and definition) of the assignment operator (with swap function) and the index [] operator?
Furthermore, are there any improvements that can be made to the other methods to improve functionality?

```
// Overloading operators for Array class
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

// A class to represent an integer array
class Array{
private:
    int *ptr;
    int size;
public:
    Array(int *p = NULL, int s = 0);
    Array(const Array&);
    ~Array();
    Array& operator= (Array);

    // Overloading [] operator to access elements in array style
    int &operator[] (int);

    // Utility function to print contents
    void print() const;

    friend void swap(Array& first, Array& second);};


// Implementation of [] operator.  This function must return a
// reference as array element can be put on left side
int &Array::operator[](int index){   
    if (index >= size || index < 0){
       throw out_of_range("Index out of Range error");
    }
    return ptr[index];
}

// constructor for array class
Array::Array(int *p, int s){
    size = s;
    ptr = NULL;
    if (s != 0){
        ptr = new int[s];
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
            ptr[i] = p[i];}
}

// destructor for array class
Array::~Array(){
    delete[] ptr;
    ptr = NULL;}

// copy constructor for array class
Array::Array(const Array& A) { 
    size = A.size;
    ptr  = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ptr[i] = A.ptr[i];}

//swap friend function of assignment operator
void swap(Array& first, Array& second){
    using std::swap;
    swap(first.size, second.size);
    swap(first.ptr, second.ptr);}

//Assignment operator for array class
Array& Array::operator=(Array other){
    swap(*this, other); 
    return *this;}

//print function for array elements
void Array::print() const{
    cout << "{";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout<<ptr[i]<<" ";
    cout<<"}"<<endl;}

// Driver program to test above methods
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    Array arr1(a, 6);
    arr1[0] = 7;
    arr1.print();
    Array arr2 = arr1;
    arr2.print();
    arr1[-1] = 4;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your edit invalidated an answer, which breaks the question-and-answer nature of this site.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a code review so much as help on how to get this to compile.

- `Array::Array(int *p = NULL, int s = 0){` default parameters go on the declaration, not the definition.*
- `Array::Array& operator=(Array other){` Qualify the `operator` with `Array::`, not the return type. You're not returning an `Array::Array`**, you're defining the `operator=` member function of `Array`
- `void Array::swap(Array& first, Array& second){` swap is not a member of array, it's a friend. Remove the `Array::`

*This is because the *client* (caller) to the method needs to know what the defaults are supposed to be, since default parameters are mostly a syntactic shortcut. If you put the defaults into the definition (e.g. a cpp/.o file), a client which includes the header cannot see the definition and thus cannot use them. In other words, there exists no `Array::Array()` constructor right now, there's only the `Array::Array(int *, int)`, but through C++ magic it can look as though `Array::Array()` is being called.

** An `Array::Array` type is impossible because you can't name a child type the same as its parent type. It would be ambiguous with the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Is it possible to avoid the Aborted (core dumped) message when the out_of_range error is thrown?

Comment: Furthermore, how would one implement a try-catch statement for invalid index values?

Comment: I would argue that you should not throw an exception on [], but that's debatable. My reasoning is that [] is canonically a dangerous operation in C++, and should be semantically thought of as a dereference of a potentially out-of-bounds address, usable *only* if you're absolutely certain it will not fail. This type of dangerous operation is integral to C++ since there's no convenient layer below it to handle it better. A method call like `GetAt(IndexType)` or something might throw by testing the bounds -- not by catching another exception, the class knows whether the argument is valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't `using namespace std;` - especially not in a header, where it inflicts the harm on every source that includes the header.

Prefer `nullptr` to `NULL`, because the former is more strongly typed.

Use `std::size_t` for indexing, rather than `int`.

When overloading `operator[]`, it's usually necessary to provide two versions:

```
int& operator[](std::size_t);
int const& operator[](std::size_t) const;
```

Usually, `operator[]` doesn't throw.  Provide a separate "checked" interface if your clients need that as well.  That's normally named `at()`.